# Is there a way to create a "Profile" automatically with a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to create a Chrome extension which creates a new profile on behalf of the user and configure specific settings for that profile and that profile only(Sort of like how Brave does "Tor in Private Browsing" mode). I used contextual identities to create similar functionality for Firefox, but in order to maintain Chrome compatibility I have to find an analogous system to use in Chrome and Profiles seems to be the only one that fits.

However, I can find no references to anyone creating a profile from an extension at all nor can I find an example of an extension that does this. Does such functionality exist? If not, does anyone know of a way that I can accomplish something comparable?

Comment: No, there's no such [extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

Comment: I suppose only way to do it for chrome now is make full copy of browser.